# Data Indexing R

Tags: r

I have data and the corresponding index. How can I make a new vector with the correct index and the rest filled with NA's?

For example:

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
index <- c(2,4,5,8,10)
```

Desired result:

```
result <- c(NA,1,NA,2,3,NA,NA,4,NA,5)
```

Comment: See `help("match")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a vector of the correct size (I assumed is was as long as the largest index but it can be any number bigger than that) an then just used the index to populate it with the values.

```
result <- rep(NA, max(index))
result[index] <- data
```

Comment: Same idea in one line: `replace(rep(NA, max(index)), index, data)` (+1)